# AlarmManager.setRepeating() not repeating on correct time

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am trying to make a prototype application in which the AlarmManager needs to repeatedly(like, in every 5 seconds) perform certain operation. Its repeating whatever execution of code in onRecieve() method of my BroadcastReciever but it repeats in 1 minutes something even if its supposed to repeat in every 5 seconds. I have followed all the tutorials, I am pretty sure I am following all steps. Can somebody help to find why its repeating late every time?

AlarmRecurring.java

```
    public class AlarmRecurring extends AppCompatActivity {

  private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_recurring);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
    setupButtons();

  }

  private void setupButtons()
  {
    findViewById(R.id.stopRepeating).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        cancel();
      }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.startRepeating).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        startrepeating();
      }
    });

  }


  public void cancel() {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  public void startrepeating() {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    EditText secondsToRepeat =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondsToRepeat);
    int repeat = Integer.parseInt(secondsToRepeat.getText().toString());

        /* Repeating on every 20 minutes interval */
    TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tp.getCurrentHour());
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tp.getCurrentMinute());
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * repeat, pendingIntent);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Repeating Alarm Started at every: " + repeat + "secs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    MediaPlayer mp=null;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
        Toast.makeText(context, "Repeating Alarm running at:" + new Date().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context , R.raw.short_notice);
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're registering the alarm to be run every 5 seconds? I can't be sure of that with the code you've posted. Also pay attention to the Note in this [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent)) and try to modify your code to use one-time alarms.

Comment: @JanithaR   Well, once I use AlarmManager.setrepeating(), it should set the alarm right when executed. And I am using a broadcast receiver which is executing properly. So its setting the alarm for sure, but just not following accuracy on time.

Comment: I'm sorry I just realised the link I posted earlier is little messed up. "Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact." Are you aware of this?

Comment: Thanks, I just switched to a different component for a while, I will have to use setWindow() then when I get to implement the strict scheduling of alarms.

Answer (score 1):

As of API 22 the value of the interval will be forced up to 60000 ms if the given value is smaller.

Comment: This helped me a lot. I can't find where it is documented, but it seems to be a real minimum.

Answer (score 0):

there is some android targetsdkversion.

Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is not proper:

android OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. Te Os has given the new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees;

- setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent);
- setExact(int, long, PendingIntent);

Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.